# How do I properly import a project to Android Studio?

Tags: android, github, android-studio

How do I properly import a project to Android Studio from github?
When I attempt to import the projects from github that is about a year old, I would get errors, and not have a functional project.

https://github.com/baseball435/SpaceInvaders

If I import the project above,
I get this message:
[image]

In addition, I get an awkward structure :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To import into Android Studio, select File > Import, and then select the directory containing the project to import. A wizard will open and guide you through the rest of the import process. When the project import has finished, it will open up a file called "import-summary.txt" which lists all the steps taken during import and suggestions for next steps. For example, it may note files that were not migrated, it may note missing components in your SDK install, and so on.

Comment: That's a useful answer but maybe you'd want to edit it a little bit and make it more readable/presentable. I'd suggest you use bullet points as they are more readable than a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in importing projects from Github.
I think you should import only the SpaceInvaders-android part.
After import a gradle rebuild is all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the [Importing github project](http://maxrohde.com/2014/08/18/import-github-project-to-android-studio/) you need. Just follow the steps.

1. Install git for Windows

   > It can be downloaded for free from [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/downloads).
2. Link git executable to Android Studio

   > Open Android Studio and got to Settings. In the Setting dialog open the page Version Control / Git. Here define the path to the git executable you have just installed.
3. Get the Path to your Repository from Github

   > Go to the GitHub page and get the HTTPs path to your repository.
4. Import the Git project to Android Studio

   > Go to Android Studio and go to Menu / VCS / Checkout from Version Control / Git

Comment: Why can't I just download the entire folder given, and import the files?

Comment: do u want to use it as library??

Comment: I just want to be able to view the code, and run the program on an android device

Comment: as u have github account and you are importing it from github  then u can do the steps.I think it's easy enough to do this then downloading and importing.